# Limit of expression involving the floor function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How could I solve this series limit:$$ x_n=\frac{[x]+[3^2x]+[5^2x]+\ldots+[(2n-1)^2x]}{n^3}$$ where $[\cdot]$ is the floor function. I need to find the limit of $x_n$ as $n\to\infty$. Tried using $x-1<[x]\leq x$ but it didn't help much.

Comment: what is $x$ here? I'm guessing you want $\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{j=1}^n \lceil (2j-1)^2x\rceil$ for some fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: x is a real number and [x] is the integral part.Im asked t find the limit for x_n,which what I understand means the limit as n goes to infinity .

Comment: You left out an x i think in the numerator. For centered dots try the command \cdots.

Comment: By the way, knowing $x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x$ is extremely helpful in this problem.

Comment: I don't understand the relation between $x$ and $x_n$ - could you tell us the value of  $x_1$ ?

Comment: it doens't give any value for x1 in the book it only says to find the limit for x_n. @zhw. I tried using it but I got to a weird sum and I'm pretty sure I used it wrong. I got to sum of off numbers ^2

Comment: The sum you probably found was $1+3^2 + 5^2 + \ldots + (2n-1)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2$ which by expanding the square is equal to $4\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 - 4 \sum_{k=1}^n k + \sum_{k=1}^n 1$. The last sum is easy, the second one is [the sum of the first $n$ integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) and the first one the [sum of the first $n$ squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number). You can find several derivations of these on this site by searching.

Comment: Hint: let $\displaystyle\,y_n=\frac{1+3^2+5^2+\ldots+(2n-1)^2}{n^3}x\,$, then $\displaystyle y_n - \frac{1}{n^2} \lt x_n \le y_n\,$.

Comment: It looks quite easy,thank you, I've never seen that sum before so I thought I probably calculated something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x-1 < \lfloor x \rfloor \le x\\
3^2x-1 < \lfloor 3^2x \rfloor \le 3^2x\\
5^2x-1 < \lfloor 5^2x \rfloor \le 5^2x\\\vdots\\
(2n-1)^2x-1 < \lfloor (2n-1)^2x \rfloor \le (2n-1)^2x\\$$sum of them

$$x(1+3^2+5^2+...+2n-1)^2-n <  \lfloor x \rfloor +\lfloor 3^2x \rfloor+...+\lfloor (2n-1)^2x \rfloor \le x(1+3^2+5^2+...+2n-1)^2\\$$
now find 
$$1^2+2^2+3^2+...+(2n)^2=\frac{2n(2n+1)(4n+1)}{6}\\
1^2+3^2+...+(2n-1)^2+(2^2+4^2+...(2n)^2)=\frac{2n(2n+1)(4n+1)}{6}\\
1^2+3^2+...+(2n-1)^2+2^2(1^2+2^2+...(n)^2)=\frac{2n(2n+1)(4n+1)}{6}\\$$so 
$$1^2+3^2+...+(2n-1)^2=\frac{2n(2n+1)(4n+1)}{6}-4(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6})\sim \frac{16n^3}{6}-4\frac{2n^3}{6}\sim \frac{8}{6}n^3$$
by using squeeze theory
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x(1+3^2+5^2+...+2n-1)^2-n}{n^3}<\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{[x]+[3^2x]+[5^2x]+\ldots+[(2n-1)^2x]}{n^3}<\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x(1+3^2+5^2+...+2n-1)^2}{n^3}\\
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x(1+3^2+5^2+...+2n-1)^2-n}{n^3}<\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{[x]+[3^2x]+[5^2x]+\ldots+[(2n-1)^2x]}{n^3}<\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x(1+3^2+5^2+...+2n-1)^2}{n^3}\\$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{8}{6}n^3-n}{n^3}\leq\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n\leq\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{8}{6}n^3}{n^3}\\\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=\frac{8}{6} $$

Comment: You subtracted $2/6$ from $16/6$ when you should have subtracted $4$ times add much. Thereafter, you should replace each $14/6$ with $4/3$.

Answer (score 1):

The identity function overestimates floor function by $<1$. Since $\sum_{j=1}^n(2j-1)^2\in\frac{4}{3}n^3+o(n^3)$, the $n$ terms in the numerator of $x_n$ have a sum $\in\frac{4}{3}n^3x+o(n^3)-\mathcal{0}(n)$. Dividing out $n^3$, only $\frac{4x}{3}$ survives as $n\to\infty$, regardless of $x$.